# Publishing a non thesis article

Tags: publications, thesis, masters, ethics

I would like to ask to you about a topic that has been on my mind right now. Before publishing my master thesis, I want to publish a non-thesis article and use it in my thesis and I want to cite myself in my thesis .I want to publish one of the new results of my thesis by using  a different method(not same method) in my non-thesis article. So would this be ethical or unethical? I am a little bit confused. Thanks for your answers and guidances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fine as you describe it. But note that the "article", if published first, needs to be cited in the thesis as you would any other article. Also, if you give up copyright to the article then you are limited in how much you can properly "quote" from the published work - just as if it were written by another.

I see two issues, however. Publishing takes a while so your thesis may need to quote a "not quite published" article. The other is that you should probably seek advice from your advisor.

But, in general, it is perfectly ethical to quote and cite your own work. It is necessary, actually, when you write something that extends something you wrote and published earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments :) It seems possible to me ,too . I will speak this in details with my advisor. Maybe one of its disadvantage can be  increase the rate of plagiarism of the thesis.

Comment: @Buffy Most copyright agreements I've read explicitly allow including the material in a thesis by an author; and it seems extremely unlikely to me that operating under the assumption that all journals work this way would end badly.